# what does the error "IndexError: tuple index out of range" mean in python?

Tags: python, index-error

I was trying to clean up my code instead of using a bunch of if statements to functions. Here is my code:

```
def tic(inpinp, board, qweqwe):
    global lik 
    ink = inpinp - 1
    lik = board.insert(ink, qweqwe)


lis = ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ',  '  ', '  ']

p = input("Player 1, would you like to be X or O?")
inpu = int(input("Where would you like to go?"))






print('{}|{}|{}'.format())
print('--|--|--'.format())
print('{}|{}|{}'.format())
print("--|--|--".format())
print('{}|{}|{}'.format())
```

Comment: oops! actually, my code begins with lik = 0

Comment: For the record, I answered the question from your title as relates to the code in the question body, but I have no idea how what you posted has anything to do with converting `if` statements to functions or the like; the function you defined is never called, and none of this really makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're wondering why you get an `IndexError` from the above code (since there are no explicit `tuple`s or indexing going on in it).

`'{}|{}|{}'.format()` implicitly means `'{0}|{1}|{2}'.format()`, where the `0`, `1` and `2` [indicate indices into the positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) passed to [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Problem is, you didn't pass any arguments, so when it indexes the `tuple` of arguments with `0`, it immediately fails, raising `IndexError`. You need to pass as many arguments as you provided placeholders for in the format string.